# Suppose $G$ is a group of order $pqr$ with $p<q<r$ and $q\nmid r-1$ for primes $p,q,r$. Prove that there is only one subgroup of order $q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group of order $pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are prime numbers such that $p<q<r$. If $q\nmid r-1$ prove that there is only one subgroup of order $q$.

By the Sylow theorems we know that the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ is in the form of $qk+1$ and has to be one of $\{1,p,r,pr\}$ but since $p<q$ and $q\nmid r-1$ it can only be $1$ or $pr$. How do I show that $pr$ is not possible?

Comment: There would be $pr(q-1)$ elements of order $q$, and hence only $pr$ other elements, but then there would be a normal Sylow $r$-subgroup, which would in turn imply a normal subgroup of order $rq$, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Your arguments looked very nice to me, but I couldn’t come up with the contradiction here. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Koro but the subgroup of order $pr$ and $qr$ can share some elements, specifically the ones of the order $r$.

Comment: A normal subgroup of order $rq$ has a normal subgroup of order $q$, which is characteristic and therefore normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution essentially given in the comments.

If there are $pr$ Sylow $q$-subgroups, then the normalizer of a Sylow $q$-subgroup has order $q$.

Counting elements shows that there is a normal Sylow $r$-subgroup in $G$. Hence there is a subgroup of order $qr$ in $G$.

But if $q \nmid r-1$, a group of order $qr$ has a normal subgroup of order $q$. So the normalizer of a Sylow $q$-subgroup will be too big, a contradiction.